# what is the event fired when typing/editing the cell in JTable

Tags: jtable

I have JTable and JButton components in the same frame.By default the JButton is disabled.I have certain number of rows in JTable.During typing/editing the cell itself,JButton component should be enabled and also to be ensure that after editing if the old value and edited value are same then JButton should be disabled.Please help me out how to write this code.Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The event is a propertyChangeEvent with the name "tableCellEditor".
If you look at the source for JTable.setCellEditor() you can see where it is fired.
If you want to get notified when a value in the table has actually changed, you need to hook into the table model.

Here is an interesting link that may be helpful:

[http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener)

Comment: Upon selection of the cell,event is fired but during typing/deleting/updating the cell itself event should be notified.I have tried the above said to my knowledge,event is fired upon selection or after tabbed out but not when typing.I have tried with cell editor component as JTextField and the value is "ABC" and by default JButton is disabled.Upon selection of the cell button should not be enabled.Only during typing only say updated to "ABCD" (note:didn't tabbed out) At the time of pressing 'D' only JButton should be enabled. Thanks for the help.